# VBA Create table for each filter data in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make a table for each unique value of a column. I used autofilter to select each filter to then copy and paste to another sheet. Due to the amount of data (large) i would like to automate and maybe do a for each cycle where each filter is select individually and copied to a differente sheet. It´s this even possible? Does anyone knows how to maybe simplify this problem ?

Comment: Did you try `Remove duplicate` function? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-and-remove-duplicates-00e35bea-b46a-4d5d-b28e-66a552dc138d (`Remove duplicate values` section)

Comment: It´s important for the analysis to keep the duplicates... however i just want to split my table in different tables considering the items in a column

Comment: 1) Copy the whole original table to a new sheet.
2) delete duplicates on the new sheet.
3) thereby getting a table with unique values.
Does this logic work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateTables()

    Const COL_FILTER = 1 ' A
    Const SHT_NAME = "Sheet1" ' data sheet

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, iLastRow As Long, i As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHT_NAME)

    ' get list as unique values
    Dim dict, key, ar
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, COL_FILTER).End(xlUp).Row
    ar = ws.Cells(1, COL_FILTER).Resize(iLastRow, 1)
    For i = 2 To iLastRow
        dict(ar(i, 1)) = 1
    Next

    ' confirm
    If MsgBox(dict.Count & " sheets will be created," & _
              " continue ? ", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' apply autofilter in turn
    ' copy to new sheet
    Set rng = ws.UsedRange
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    For Each key In dict
        With wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
            .Name = CStr(key)
            rng.AutoFilter COL_FILTER, CStr(key)
            rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Range("A1")
            .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .UsedRange, , xlYes) _
                .Name = "Table " & key
        End With
        MsgBox "Created sheet " & key
    Next
    
    MsgBox dict.Count & " sheets created"
End Sub
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for !!! Thank you very much ! 

I just have another question, some values have invalid characters like \ and º theres any way to work round this problem? 

Once again thank you all for your time and help!

Comment: @Catia Are those in the original data or the copies ? What do you want to replace them with, a space ? There is a range method [replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Replace)

Comment: Hi! The data was converted from pdf to excel so the problem migh be there. However, i've follow your method replace suggestion and it works just fine ! Thank you very much