# select data from one sheet and copy them to new different workbooks based on a specific colum value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet like the following one (the real sheet contains 120 columns)

[image]

I would like to select the data based on the value of the Category column D, and create a new workbook by category with the total amount of each category.

So based on the sheet above, I would like using VBA code to create new workbooks, one for each category (something like New Worbook called category A, New Worbook called category B  etc...)

[image: Workbook for category A]

[image: Workbook for category B]

I know how to create a new workbook, but I don't know how to select the data by category (unique) before creating a new workbook and paste them into the new workbook. Should I create a loop for and test the value for each cell in the colum D ? should I use filters to filter unique values ?

can any of you guide or help me on how to do that please ?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/8422953)

Comment: before writing the code, I need to know by how to start, a loop for on the column ? a filter ? that's what I am asking.... all I did is a code to create a new workbook from a first workbook and am stucked cuz I don't know how to filter the data that I want, i can copy all the sheet to another workbook but that's not what I want

Comment: There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67474690/vba-create-table-for-each-filter-data-in-another-sheet/67490737#67490737). The unique values are determined using a dictionary.

Comment: Create a reference to the range. Decide which columns you want to copy (reference this range). Use a dictionary to hold the unique values from the category column. Loop through the keys of the dictionary. Use `AutoFilter` to filter the range by the current key of the dictionary. Create a new one-worksheet workbook. Copy the intersection of the visible cell's entire rows and the desired columns to the workbook, save & close it and repeat. Add the code you've got and add the previously mentioned missing details.

Comment: @VBasic2008 thanks that's a very usefull comment and hint, please tell me how to add the different data to the range ? I use something like Union ? and if I used the autofilter to filter the data that I want, how to select the result of autofilter ? i mean if I do something like select range ("A1:A10") it will select only the visible lines or all of them ? thanks again I will follow the instructions that you gave me

Comment: You will use something like `Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` possibly expanded with `.EntireRow` and `Intersect(..., Desired Columns)`. Here are some of [my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a9814069%20AutoFilter) using `AutoFilter` (and `SpecialCells`). There could be even one or more of them that exactly match your requirements. Try to get something together and post the code so we can 'fill in the blanks'.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will check all that and come back to confirm for you tomorrow if I succeded to do what I want

Comment: @VBasic2008 I just posted how I made it work, since no one proposed a solution, so it may be helpfull if one day anyone has the same question. Thanks a lot for you, because you are the only one who tried to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work, so I will post my own answer, to help anyone who has a similar work to do.
Thanks to anyone who read this question or tried to help even if he couldn't.

```
Public Sub LaunchProg() 

Call FilterData
Call CreateCategoriesFiles
 
End Sub


Public Sub FilterData()
'This Sub will filter data to get a colum with unique values of categories after joining column CX and CY


'"CX" contains first column of categories 
'"CY"  contains second column of categories 


Dim MyColumn As String
Dim MyLastRow As Long
Dim SheetGroupe5 As Worksheet
Dim TempData As Worksheet

Dim RangeToFilter As String
Dim RangeFiltered As String

Dim StartAt As Integer

Dim copyFrom As String
Dim copyTo As String
Dim ToColumn As String


  Const TempRegA As String = "E"
  Const TempRegB As String = "F"
  Const TempRegAB As String = "G"
 Const TempHeader As Integer = 1


Set SheetGroupe5 = Groupe5

Set TempData = Tempo 

'Copiying Data from the sheet called Groupe5 (Column CX) , to a temporary sheet called TempData 

MyColumn = "CX"

'Range that we want to filter
RangeToFilter = MyColumn & ":" & MyColumn
'Destination range after filtering
RangeFiltered = TempRegA & TempHeader & ":" & TempRegA & TempHeader
'select the data using AdvancedFilter
'copy the selection to TempData
SheetGroupe5.Range(RangeToFilter).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , TempData.Range(RangeFiltered), True

'Copiying Data from the sheet called Groupe5 (Column CY) , to a temporary sheet called TempData 
MyColumn = "CY"

'Range that we want to filter
RangeToFilter = MyColumn & ":" & MyColumn
'Destination range after filtering
RangeFiltered = TempRegB & TempHeader & ":" & TempRegB & TempHeader
'select the data using AdvancedFilter
'copy the selection to TempData
SheetGroupe5.Range(RangeToFilter).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , TempData.Range(RangeFiltered), True


'Copy the 2 columns of category into 1 column
'First column
MyColumn = TempRegA
MyLastRow = GetLastRow(TempData, MyColumn)

StartAt = TempHeader + 1
ToColumn = TempRegAB

If MyLastRow >= TempHeader + 1 Then

copyFrom = MyColumn & StartAt & ":" & MyColumn & MyLastRow
copyTo = ToColumn & StartAt & ":" & ToColumn & MyLastRow

TempData.Range(copyFrom).Copy TempData.Range(copyTo)

End If 'If MyLastRow >= StartAt Then

'second column

MyColumn = TempRegB
MyLastRow = GetLastRow(TempData, MyColumn)
StartAt = GetLastRow(TempData, ToColumn) + 1

If MyLastRow >= TempHeader + 1 Then

copyFrom = MyColumn & TempHeader + 1 & ":" & MyColumn & MyLastRow
copyTo = ToColumn & StartAt & ":" & ToColumn & (MyLastRow + StartAt)

TempData.Range(copyFrom).Copy TempData.Range(copyTo)

End If 'If MyLastRow >= StartAt Then

'Filter the data of the new created column using AdvancedFilter to get unique values


MyColumn = TempRegAB
MyLastRow = GetLastRow(TempData, MyColumn)
RangeToFilter = MyColumn & ":" & MyColumn
Debug.Print RangeToFilter

RangeFiltered = "D" & TempHeader & ":" & "D" & TempHeader

TempData.Range(RangeToFilter).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , TempData.Range(RangeFiltered), True

TempData.Range("A1").AutoFilter
Groupe5.Range("A1").AutoFilter

End Sub


Public Function GetLastRow(TheSheet As Worksheet, ColName As String) As Long
'Get last row of a given column for a given sheet
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = TheSheet.Columns(ColName).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

GetLastRow =LastRow

End Function




Public Sub CreateClientsFiles()
'This sub will create a workbook for each category after selecting the corresponding data for each category using the AutoFilter

'"CZ" contains all categories that I want to convert into files

Dim SheetGroupe5 As Worksheet
Dim TempData As Worksheet

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyExtension As String
Dim StartAt As Integer
Dim DistinctRange As String
Dim vArray As Variant
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsNewSht As Worksheet

Dim sCriteria1 As String
Dim sCriteria2 As String


Dim MyColumn As String
Dim RangeToFilter As String
Dim MyNewName As String
Dim FullFileName As String
Dim ToRange As String

Dim sFormulaMonth As String
Dim sFormulaYear As String

Const TempHeader As Integer = 1
Const Groupe5Header As Integer = 1


MyFolder = "C:\MyFolder\"
MyExtension = ".xlsx"


Set SheetGroupe5 = Groupe5

Set TempData = Tempo 

'I have another temporay sheet called DataToFile 
'I will store at this sheet each category before saving it to a workbook
Set wsNewSht = DataToFile

StartAt = TempHeader + 1


MyColumn = "D"

MyLastRow = GetLastRow(TempData, MyColumn)
DistinctRange = MyColumn & StartAt & ":" & MyColumn & MyLastRow
vArray = TempData.Range(DistinctRange).Value2

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

iCol = 1

With SheetGroupe5

For iRow = 1 To UBound(vArray, 1)

MyNewName = vArray(iRow, iCol)


'Criterias based on my data
sCriteria1 = vArray(iRow, iCol) & " - " & "*"
sCriteria2 = "*" & " - " & vArray(iRow, iCol)
 

    .AutoFilterMode = False 
     MyLastRow = GetLastRow(SheetGroupe5, "CZ")
     RangeToFilter = "CZ" & Groupe5Header & ":" & "CZ" & MyLastRow
     
    .Range(RangeToFilter).AutoFilter Field:=104, Criteria1 _
     :=sCriteria1, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=sCriteria2
  
      
    'Rename the sheet using the category Name
    wsNewSht.Name = MyNewName
    wsNewSht.Cells.Clear
    .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
   Destination:=wsNewSht.Range("A1")
   
    'Create a new workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    wsNewSht.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)

MyNewName = vArray(iRow, iCol)
    
    FullFileName = MyFolder & MyNewName & MyExtension
    wb.SaveAs FullFileName
      
    wb.Close savechanges:=True
    
Next iRow

'Apply back Autofilter
.ShowAllData
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```